# Create entirely custom Magento customer login form

Tags: forms, magento, authentication

How can I create my own login form on frontend? I don’t just want to modify the template of the existing login form, but I would like to create my own.

I am using Magento Community 1.7.

Thank you for any guidance you could give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new template and override the layout xml to insert your own block.

Comment: I would like to keep the original login, so not replacing the existing one. If I make an override in layout.xml, I lose the original login form.

Comment: You can override just the block that the form sits in without losing any of the formatting of the original page. gazarsgo has the most accurate answer you'll find without someone writing the code for you. You're options are override or leave the original in place.

Comment: You could also create a new controller, or override the existing controller and add a new action in order to have everything explicitly separated by defining your own layout, but that seems like a lot of unnecessary extra work.